# MarkItUp: Tab/Indent, Set Selection

Tags: javascript, markitup

I see that theres is no build in way for doing tabs/indents in MarkItUp? So I did something like

```
onTab: { 
  keepDefault: false, 
  replaceWith: function(markItUp) { 
    return miu.openEachLineWith(markItUp, '  '); 
  }
},
openEachLineWith: function(markItUp, openingStr) {
  var textarea = markItUp.textarea,
      selStart = textarea.selectionStart,
      selEnd = textarea.selectionEnd,
      selText = textarea.value.substring(selStart, selEnd),
      lines = [], 
      charsAdded = 0;

  lines = selText.split(/\r?\n/);
  for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
    lines[i] = openingStr + lines[i];
    charsAdded += openingStr.length;
  }
  textarea.selectionEnd = selEnd + charsAdded;
  return lines.join('\n');
}
```

which works but, how can I set the selection after replacing the the text, I want it to select the tabbed text, also I prefer the way the editor here on SO works where when I bold some text, it selects the bolded text instead of moving the cursor to the end, can I do that with markItUp too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on a script to do this. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/dp2WL/2/

It indents when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed and outdents when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed and doesn't require any library. It hasn't had as much testing as I'd like, but seems to work well in all major browsers, including IE 6. The main code comes from [an open source project I'm working on](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/). The bit that enables tab indentation is at the bottom:

```
window.onload = function() {
    rangyInputs.init();
    rangyInputs.enableTabIndentation(document.getElementById("test"), "    ");
};
```

Comment: I realize this is a little old, but I'm looking for a way to indent and outdent text in a textarea using tab and shift+tab and I just thought I'd mention that at least in the latest version of Chrome when tab is pressed in your fiddle only one space is added (shift+tab removes four spaces, though).

Comment: @Nate: Works fine for me in my Chrome. Version is 30.0.1599.69.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the selection in the **afterInsert** callback (not in **replaceWith**)